# sshd not always available

Tags: raspbian, ssh

I just updated my old Pi to a new Raspbian image from 6/20/2014.  It seems that ssh is extremely flaky now.  When I'm on a terminal on the actual Pi, all network access seems to work just fine.  However, from the outside I ssh seems to come up and down, at random:

```
brianz@mbp-brianz (master=)$ ssh 192.168.1.31
ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.31 port 22: Host is down
brianz@mpb-brianz (master=)$ ssh 192.168.1.31
ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.31 port 22: Host is down
brianz@mbp-brianz (master=)$ ssh 192.168.1.31
Linux raspberrypi 3.12.22+ #691 PREEMPT Wed Jun 18 18:29:58 BST 2014 armv6l

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
Last login: Tue Jun 24 22:17:33 2014 from 192.168.1.14
```

Then eventually:

```
brianz@raspberrypi ~ $ Write failed: Host is down
brianz@mbp-brianz (master=)$
```

Is this an sshd/ssh config setting or something else?

Comment: Does it aways have the same IP address?

Comment: Yup...it always gets the same IP.